# Katalon Studio integration with TeamCity - Error - com.kms.katalon.execution.exception.InvalidConsoleArgumentException: Test suite 'Test' not found

Tags: teamcity, katalon-studio

I am trying to configure Katalon studio with Teamcity to run test suite and collections. But throwing below error while running a test suite through Teamcity build.

```
    Finalize build settings
[14:31:48]The build is removed from the queue to be prepared for the start
[14:31:48]Collecting changes in 1 VCS root
[14:31:49]Starting the build on the agent TC-Agent04
[14:31:49]Clearing temporary directory: D:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[14:31:49]Publishing internal artifacts (2s)
[14:31:49]Using vcs information from agent file: 52a0c416513b6bab.xml
[14:31:49]Checkout directory: D:\BuildAgent\work\52a0c416513b6bab
[14:31:49]Updating sources: auto checkout (on agent) (1s)
[14:31:51]Step 1/2: Command Line
[14:31:51]Step 2/2: Run Katalon (Command Line) (17s)
[14:31:51][Step 2/2] Starting: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c katalon -runMode=console -projectPath=D:\BuildAgent\work\52a0c416513b6bab\qa-automation.prj -reportFolder="Reports" -reportFileName="report" -retry=0 "-testSuitePath="Test Suites/Test"" -executionProfile="kls_test_env" "-browserType="Chrome (headless)""
[14:31:51][Step 2/2] in directory: D:\agent_utils\Katalon_Studio_Windows_64-5.8.3
[14:31:56][Step 2/2] Request sent successfully.
[14:31:56][Step 2/2] Starting Groovy-Eclipse compiler resolver.  Specified compiler level: unspecified
[14:31:56][Step 2/2] 161 2.4.7.xx-201611170128-e46 = ACTIVE
[14:32:01][Step 2/2] /D%%BuildAgent%work%52a0c416513b6bab%qa-automation.prj/Keywords/browserstack/ComKeys.groovy: 29 Groovy:unable to resolve class internal.GlobalVariable
[14:32:01][Step 2/2] /D%%BuildAgent%work%52a0c416513b6bab%qa-automation.prj/Keywords/gcf/CommKeys.groovy: 21 Groovy:unable to resolve class internal.GlobalVariable
[14:32:01][Step 2/2] /D%%BuildAgent%work%52a0c416513b6bab%qa-automation.prj/Keywords/kls/CommKeys.groovy: 25 Groovy:unable to resolve class internal.GlobalVariable
[14:32:01][Step 2/2] /D%%BuildAgent%work%52a0c416513b6bab%qa-automation.prj/Keywords/kls/dbkeys.groovy: 29 Groovy:unable to resolve class internal.GlobalVariable
[14:32:03][Step 2/2] /D%%BuildAgent%work%52a0c416513b6bab%qa-automation.prj/Keywords/browserstack/ComKeys.groovy: 29 Groovy:unable to resolve class internal.GlobalVariable
[14:32:03][Step 2/2] /D%%BuildAgent%work%52a0c416513b6bab%qa-automation.prj/Keywords/gcf/CommKeys.groovy: 21 Groovy:unable to resolve class internal.GlobalVariable
[14:32:03][Step 2/2] /D%%BuildAgent%work%52a0c416513b6bab%qa-automation.prj/Keywords/kls/CommKeys.groovy: 25 Groovy:unable to resolve class internal.GlobalVariable
[14:32:03][Step 2/2] /D%%BuildAgent%work%52a0c416513b6bab%qa-automation.prj/Keywords/kls/dbkeys.groovy: 29 Groovy:unable to resolve class internal.GlobalVariable
[14:32:03][Step 2/2] /D%%BuildAgent%work%52a0c416513b6bab%qa-automation.prj/Test Listeners/KLSTestListeners.groovy: 16 Groovy:unable to resolve class internal.GlobalVariable
[14:32:05][Step 2/2] /D%%BuildAgent%work%52a0c416513b6bab%qa-automation.prj/Keywords/browserstack/ComKeys.groovy: 29 Groovy:unable to resolve class internal.GlobalVariable
[14:32:05][Step 2/2] /D%%BuildAgent%work%52a0c416513b6bab%qa-automation.prj/Keywords/gcf/CommKeys.groovy: 21 Groovy:unable to resolve class internal.GlobalVariable
[14:32:05][Step 2/2] /D%%BuildAgent%work%52a0c416513b6bab%qa-automation.prj/Test Listeners/KLSTestListeners.groovy: 16 Groovy:unable to resolve class internal.GlobalVariable
[14:32:05][Step 2/2] /D%%BuildAgent%work%52a0c416513b6bab%qa-automation.prj/Keywords/kls/CommKeys.groovy: 25 Groovy:unable to resolve class internal.GlobalVariable
[14:32:05][Step 2/2] /D%%BuildAgent%work%52a0c416513b6bab%qa-automation.prj/Keywords/kls/dbkeys.groovy: 29 Groovy:unable to resolve class internal.GlobalVariable
[14:32:08][Step 2/2] com.kms.katalon.execution.exception.ExecutionException: com.kms.katalon.execution.exception.InvalidConsoleArgumentException: Test suite 'Test' not found.
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at com.kms.katalon.execution.console.entity.TestSuiteLauncherOptionParser.getConsoleLauncher(TestSuiteLauncherOptionParser.java:113)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at com.kms.katalon.execution.console.ConsoleExecutor.execute(ConsoleExecutor.java:72)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at com.kms.katalon.execution.console.ConsoleMain.launch(ConsoleMain.java:94)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at com.kms.katalon.console.application.Application.runConsole(Application.java:76)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.runConsole(Application.java:72)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.start(Application.java:56)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at `enter code here`org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2] Caused by: com.kms.katalon.execution.exception.InvalidConsoleArgumentException: Test suite 'Test' not found.
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at com.kms.katalon.execution.console.entity.TestSuiteLauncherOptionParser.throwInvalidTestSuiteIdException(TestSuiteLauncherOptionParser.java:146)
[14:32:08][Step 2/2]    at
```

Please advise what would be the issue. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use backslashes in paths passed to whatever is digesting them here. Are those pathnames it is logging a result of not using canonical pathnames, a logging artefact, or just the way it does it? Let us know in an [edit] about the results of your research. Otherwise, there isn't much we can do to help, as this seems environmental.

Comment: That's the way it does. I have not changed anything. I have exactly followed the path patter advised by Katalon tool. The version of Katalon I am using is 5.8.

Comment: That's fine, these strings may be armored/munged. But, clearly, this process does not have the right info passed to it. Your job is to make sure that the "-testSuitePath="Test Suites/Test"" argument (**that's a strange number and placement of double quotes...**) is correct in the context of the rest of the command. Unless this command works as-is from the correct test context, it won't work in an automated fashion either.

Comment: This actually has very little to do with coding. You might have better luck researching over on https://sqa.stackexchange.com/. I'm voting to close this one.